# High-reliability transformer selection

Tags: transformer, generator, industrial

Our company has an emergency diesel generator as backup in case of electrical failure. This generator is powered by batteries to start up the genset.

In order to charge those batteries, we need a battery charger that has a 220-305 V, single-phase input and an output of 24 VDC, 20 A.

Our main supply in the panel is 380 VAC, 3-phase, 60 Hz. What kind of transformer can we use between the main supply and the battery charger? The component reliability is critical since it is in the oil and gas industry.

Comment: Your use case is pretty much standard, so most companies engage other specialist companies to provide a proven solution. As for what transformer to use, one with a 380vac primary and a 220V secondary. Should be off the shelf at most industrial electrical wholesalers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power you are talking about is 380V 3-phase. It is generally supplied in "Wye" configuration.

- If you make a connection phase to phase, you get 380V.
- If you make a connection phase to neutral, you get 220V.

That is exactly what your battery charger wants.  So you should be all set wiring it phase to neutral.

Comment: But in this way is it more reliable for oil and gas industry? I read online in order to have more reliable connection using transformer is advised and also would the phase change to one instead of three

Comment: @Moto Reliability should be better if you do not need an extra transformer. A transformer that is not present could not fail.

Comment: @Moto Yes, this is basic stuff, it's how standard Euro-style 3-phase power works lol.  It's designed to give you 220V or 380V depending on how you connect the wires.  Safety regulations require that all electrical work in an industrial context such as the oil industry be done by licensed electricians. As such your professional will know what to do.